# how to change address of variable?

Tags: c++

i have

```
Tree<std:string> tree;
```

now

```
new Tree<std:string>;
```

leads to a pointer,
how can i change address of tree to that of pointer generated by new?

Comment: Are you asking how to change the address of an *existing object*? If yes, think about what that means :-).

Comment: actually i want to assign it to some variable like java. tree=some operatio(new Tree) so that tree can be used like a normal variable without those tiring * and -> everywher

Comment: ITs already done. The second line is not required. The first line declares and initializes (using the default constructor) the variable tree.

Comment: You can't have a "normal variable" in C++, if your idea of a normal variable is a Java reference. Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Making C++ code look like Java is a bad idea, the two languages are very different.

That said, in C++ operator `new` returns a pointer to the allocated object.

```
Tree<std::string> * tree = new Tree<std::string>;
tree->do_something();
```

You can also bind a reference to your object.

```
Tree<std::string> & tree2 = *tree;
tree.do_something();
```

I urge you not to do that. Writing `->` instead of `.` is not that difficult.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're a little confused here. 
In C++ when you declare an object, the constructor is called automatically, you don't need to new it. After doing:

```
Tree<std:string> tree;
```

You can access tree already, and its constructor has been called.

It is already a constructed object. If you want to have a pointer, and construct an object in the heap, and no the stack, you need to do,

```
Tree<std:string> *tree;
tree  = new Tree<std:string>;
```

And then use *tree to access tree.
You can see how it works if you add a printf statement to the constructor.

Comment: actually i want to assign it to some variable like java.
tree=some operatio(new Tree)
so that tree can be used like a normal variable without those tiring * and -> everywhere

Comment: i need to new it to keep it on heap, i want a java like behaviour.

Comment: No can do, sorry. Why do you need it on the heap?

Comment: because there are many of them to be generated, i am parsing a number of xml files.

Comment: You won't get "java like behavior" by placing them on the heap. And there is no need to put them on the heap. Each Tree should *internally* place what it needs on the heap, so that the size of the Tree object *itself* is only a handful of bytes, and can be safely placed on the stack. Alternatively, put them in a `std::vector` or similar. Don't use pointers. You don't need them, and you're just making things difficult for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  Creating an object using `Tree<std:string> tree;` creates tree at some specific place in memory and you can't change that.

Perhaps what you want is to make tree be a pointer `Tree<std:string> *tree = 0;`.  When you do that, tree is no longer an object but a pointer.  You can then make it point to an object by assigning the return from new `tree = new Tree<std::string>;`

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend to read Alok's comment and think a bit about it.

Here you have examples of alternative approaches of transition from automatic storage to dynamic storage. It uses `std::vector` as equivalent to your `Tree` class, but it can be any type you like.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   vector<string> v(3);
   v[0] = "abc";
   v[1] = "def";
   v[2] = "ghi";

   // option #1 - make a copy
   {
      vector<string>* pv = new vector<string>(v);
      std::copy(pv->begin(), pv->end(), std::ostream_iterator<string>(cout, ", "));
      delete pv;
   }
   cout << endl;

   // option #2 - move content from original vector to new'ed one
   {
      vector<string>* pv = new vector<string>();
      pv->swap(v);
      std::copy(pv->begin(), pv->end(), std::ostream_iterator<string>(cout, ", "));
      delete pv;
   }
}
```